# WCF REST Services and jQuery

Tags: jquery, wcf, rest

I managed to create some REST services and they're perfectly accessible through the browser, e.g. http://localhost:port/uri/template/value - and it returns the value. However, I am having problems accessing it through jQuery. I have previously created MVC controller actions that I could access through $.ajax() calls, but this one has me stumped. I'm probably missing either something big, or tiny but crucial. Instead of pasting code here the VS2010 solution file has been zipped up here: http://savitarbernese.com/WCF_Prototypes.zip.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Dany.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your web pages are being served from a different port than the web services, then that's a cross domain call, and it won't work. You may need to either host the services on the same port, or else look into supporting Jsonp on them.

Comment: Bingo! A quick look at Chrome console told me this too - it didn't even occur to me. Thanks for that, I will look at setting things up on the same domain/port.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.

1. the click event on the anchor element isn't even firing, I changed that to a button and it fired like it should have.
2. The uri you are sending your request to is wrong.  You have:

http://localhost:1414/crypto.svc/sha512/createhash/?inputText=This+is+some+text

It should be:

http://localhost:1414/crypto.svc/sha512/createhash/This+is+some+text

Comment: The event was firing just fine for me - I put a breakpoint on the $.ajax error callback and it stopped right there.